# Nested for loop and 3D Plot within Class Object

Tags: python, class, for-loop, matplotlib

i am sure this is an easy problem to deal with, but i cant figure it out. I created a Borehole Class and want to compute my pore pressure around each Borehole/Well. Along a single axis, my code looks like this:

```
from scipy.special import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *


## Globale Variablen ##

rhof = 1000                                     # Dichte Flüssigkeit [kg/m³]
lameu = 11.2*10**9                              # Lamé-Parameter, undrained [GPa]
lame = 8.4*10**9                                # Lamé-Parameter, drained [GPa]
pi                                              # durch Pythonmodul "math" gegeben
alpha = 0.65                                    # Biot-Willis-Koeffizient
G = 8.4*10**9                                   # Schermodul [GPa]
k = 1.0e-15                                     # Permeabilität [m²] bzw. [Darcy] 
eta = 0.001                                     # Viskosität des Fluids [Pa*s]

## Berechnung der Parameter ##

kappa = k/eta                                                    
c = ((kappa*(lameu-lame)*(lame+2*G))/((alpha**2)*(lameu+2*G)))   

## Wertebereich ##

xmin = 0
xmax = 100
xsteps = 1.0
x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, xsteps)

## Class ##

class Bohrloch(object):
    loch_zaehler = 0

    def __init__(self, xlage, tstart, q):    # Funktion, um BL zu erzeugen
        self.xlage = xlage
        #self.ylage = ylage                  # Lage der Bohrung
        self.tstart = tstart                 # Start der Injektion/Produktion
        self.q = q                           # Fluidmenge


## Druck ##     

    def getPressure(self, t): # gibt nach Zeit t die zugehörigen Druckwerte aus
        if (t-self.tstart<0): # Fehlermeldung, falls Startpunkt nach t liegt
            return () 
            print "Startpunkt liegt außerhalb des Förderzeitraumes!"
        else:
            self.r = np.sqrt((x-self.xlage)**2)
            self.P = (self.q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,self.r**2/(4*c*(t-self.tstart))))
            #self.P[self.xlage] = 0         # gibt Bohrlochlage wieder
            self.z = self.P/1e6
            return self.z                   # Druckwerte in [MPa]


    def pressureTable (self, t, xschritt):       # erstellt Wertetabelle
        self.getPressure(t)
        for i in range (xmin, xmax, xschritt):
            print i, "  ", self.z[i]

t = 1000*24*3600
b1 = Bohrloch(50,0*24*3600,6.0/1000)
b1.pressureTable(t,1)
```

With this method i get my desired pressure table. Now i want to have a pressure table for x and y values, including an 3D Plot. This is my code so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.special import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *


## Globale Variablen ##

rhof = 1000                                     # Dichte Flüssigkeit [kg/m³]
lameu = 11.2*10**9                              # Lamé-Parameter, undrained [GPa]
lame = 8.4*10**9                                # Lamé-Parameter, drained [GPa]
pi                                              # durch Pythonmodul "math" gegeben
alpha = 0.65                                    # Biot-Willis-Koeffizient
G = 8.4*10**9                                   # Schermodul [GPa]
k = 1.0e-15                                     # Permeabilität [m²] bzw. [Darcy] 
eta = 0.001                                     # Viskosität des Fluids [Pa*s]

## Berechnung der Parameter ##

kappa = k/eta                                                     
c = ((kappa*(lameu-lame)*(lame+2*G))/((alpha**2)*(lameu+2*G)))   

## Wertebereich ##

xmin = 0
xmax = 100
xsteps = 1.0
x = np.arange(xmin,xmax,xsteps)
ymin = 0
ymax = 100
ysteps = 1.0
y = np.arange(ymin,ymax,ysteps)

## Klassendefinition ## 

class Bohrloch(object):
    loch_zaehler = 0

    def __init__(self, xlage, ylage, tstart, q):     # Funktion, um BL zu erzeugen
        self.xlage = xlage                   # x-Lage der Bohrung
        self.ylage = ylage                   # y-Lage der Bohrung
        self.tstart = tstart                 # Start der Injektion/Produktion
        self.q = q                           # Fluidmenge


## Druck ##      

    def getPressure(self, t):                
        if (t-self.tstart<0):                
            return () 
            print "Startpunkt liegt außerhalb des Förderzeitraumes!"
        else:
            self.r = np.sqrt((x-self.xlage)**2+(y-self.ylage)**2)
            self.P = (self.q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,self.r**2/(4*c*(t-self.tstart))))
            self.P[self.xlage] = np.nan
            self.P[self.ylage] = np.nan            
            self.z = self.P/1e6
            return self.z                    # Druckwerte in [MPa]

    def pressureTable (self, t, xschritt, yschritt):
        self.getPressure(t)
        for k in range (xmin, xmax, xschritt):
            for l in range (ymin, ymax, yschritt):
                # my mistake should be here?
                print k, "  ",  l, "  ",  self.z[k][l]                   

    def pressurePlot3D (self, t):
        self.getPressure(t)
        Z = self.z
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        Z[Z == np.inf] = np.nan                              
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0,
                               antialiased=False, vmin=np.nanmin(Z), vmax=np.nanmax(Z))
        fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
        ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)      # x-Achsenskala vorgeben
        ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)      # y-Achsenskala vorgeben
        ax.set_title('Druckverteilung')
        ax.set_xlabel('x-Richtung [m]')
        ax.set_ylabel('y-Richtung Well [m]')
        ax.set_zlabel('Druck in [MPa]')
        plt.show()

t = 1000*24*3600
b1 = Bohrloch(50,50,0*24*3600,6.0/1000)
b1.pressureTable(t,1)
b1.pressurePlot3D(t)
```

Unfortunately, my table doesnt work and the desired 3D Plot looks strange. I am still a total beginner in Python and need some advices.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `self.z` is not a two-dimensional array/list. Therefore, trying to access `self.z[k][l]` results in `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

---

- I do not quite understand how you want to implement the second dimension. You introduce the y-position, but then, you just calculate a 1D radius array by using both the x- and y-location in

  ```
  self.r = np.sqrt((x-self.xlage)**2+(y-self.ylage)**2)
  ```
- The next question is, what do you intend with:

  ```
  self.P[self.xlage] = np.nan
  self.P[self.ylage] = np.nan
  ```

  If you change `xsteps` and `ysteps` to `10`, and call:

  ```
  b1 = Bohrloch(2,3,0*24*3600,6.0/1000)
  print b1.getPressure(t)
  ```

  Your output will be:

  ```
  [ 5.44152501 4.40905986        nan        nan  2.87481753  2.64950827
    2.46756653 2.31503845 2.18379093 2.06866598]
  ```

  Why would you want to replace the 3rd and 4th elements with `nan`?

---

These issues are also at the basis of your plotting routine. Because you now have `np.nan` values in your array, these won't show in the plot. Because `self.z` is not two-dimensional, you are probably not getting the surface you may be expecting:

[image: original]

---

Here's a simple way of coming up with a 2D implementation. I am not familiar enough with what you are trying to do, but it gets the idea across:

```
    def getPressure(self, t):                
        if (t-self.tstart<0):                
            return () 
            print "Startpunkt liegt außerhalb des Förderzeitraumes!"
        else:

            # you need to initialize r, P and z as list of lists
            # make this dependent on your x coordinates
            # the second dimension will grow dynamically

            self.r = [[] for ri in range(len(x))]
            self.P = [[] for ri in range(len(x))]
            self.z = [[] for ri in range(len(x))]

            # iterate through both x and y independently

            for ii in range(len(x)):
                for jj in range(len(y)):

            # append to the list that corresponds to the current x -value
            # also, use x[ii] and y[jj] to call one x-, y-value at a time  

                    self.r[ii].append(np.sqrt((x[ii]-self.xlage)**2+(y[jj]-self.ylage)**2))

            # calling r[ii][-1] ensures you are using the value that was last added to the list:

                    self.P[ii].append((self.q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,self.r[ii][-1]**2/(4*c*(t-self.tstart)))))

                    self.z[ii].append(self.P[ii][-1]/1e6)

            # now, you can use xlage and ylage to blank one value
            # do this for both P and z, because z is now calculated inside the loop

            self.P[self.xlage][self.ylage] = np.nan
            self.z[self.xlage][self.ylage] = np.nan

            return self.z
```

From your plotting routine, remove this line: `Z[Z == np.inf] = np.nan`, use your original command:

```
b1 = Bohrloch(50,50,0*24*3600,6.0/1000)  
b1.pressurePlot3D(t)
```

and you will now get this plot:

[image: new]

Comment: hi Schorsch, i also have to calculate stresses around my borehole. I will edit my question, maybe you can help me. would be awesome!

Comment: @Alex: Please ask a new question. That keeps it cleaner. You can link back to this question

Comment: oh no, too late. Sry! Should i still open a new question? Or do you want to try it here?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, please ask a new question. I'll roll back the edit. Thanks

Comment: @Alex, I did look at your code. You might want to consider not asking that question, it might get downvoted. Instead, make sure you use `self.factor2[ii]` and `self.factor2[ii][-1]` (instead of just `self.factor`). Also, pull the `/1e6` inside the last `)` - it has to be part of what is being appended.