# Return all values in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, return, return-value

i have the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.special import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *
import csv



## Globale Variablen ##
rhof = 1000                                     # Dichte Flüssigkeit [kg/m³]
lameu = 11.2*10**9                              # Lamé-Parameter, undrained [GPa]
lame = 8.4*10**9                                # Lamé-Parameter, drained [GPa]
pi                                              # durch Pythonmodul "math" gegeben
alpha = 0.65                                    # Biot-Willis-Koeffizient
G = 8.4*10**9                                   # Schermodul [GPa]
k = 1.0e-15                                     # Permeabilität [m²] bzw. [Darcy] 
eta = 0.001                                     # Viskosität des Fluids [Pa*s]

## Berechnung der Parameter ##
kappa = k/eta                                                    
c = ((kappa*(lameu-lame)*(lame+2*G))/((alpha**2)*(lameu+2*G)))   

## Wertebereich ##
xmin = 0
xmax = 50
xsteps = 1
x = np.arange(xmin,xmax,xsteps)
ymin = 0
ymax = 50
ysteps = 1
y = np.arange(ymin,ymax,ysteps)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

## Klassendefinition ##  
class Bohrloch(object):
    loch_zaehler = 0

    def __init__(self, xlage, ylage, tstart, q):     # Funktion, um BL zu erzeugen
        self.xlage = xlage                   # x-Lage der Bohrung
        self.ylage = ylage                   # y-Lage der Bohrung
        self.tstart = tstart                 # Start der Injektion/Produktion
        self.q = q                           # Fluidmenge


######################### Druck ###############################################     

     def getPressure(self, t):    
        if (t-self.tstart<0):   
            return () 
            print "Startpunkt liegt außerhalb des Förderzeitraumes!"
        else:
            for x in range (xmin, xmax, xsteps):
                for y in range (ymin,ymax,ysteps):
                    self.r = sqrt((x-self.xlage)**2+(y-self.ylage)**2)
                    self.P = (self.q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,self.r**2/(4*c*(t-self.tstart))))
                    self.z = self.P/1e6 #= self.P/1e6
                    #print self.z
                    return self.z
```

I want to have all values out of my loop, not only the last/first one. If i comment `return self.z` and uncomment `print self.z`, all values are displayed, but i want to return all of them. I read about the `yield` possibility, but i didn't really understand it. I am looking for the most simpliest solution; any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: On `yield`, see [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Comment: What's wrong with [the answer you got here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27485360/2043505)?

Comment: @Schorsch: it's fine, thx! i'm just trying to understand my issue as best as possible, therefore i asked here for my loop values only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list, append each item to it, and return it at the end of the function.

```
 def getPressure(self, t):    
    if (t-self.tstart<0):   
        return () 
        print "Startpunkt liegt außerhalb des Förderzeitraumes!"
    else:
        result = []
        for x in range (xmin, xmax, xsteps):
            for y in range (ymin,ymax,ysteps):
                self.r = sqrt((x-self.xlage)**2+(y-self.ylage)**2)
                self.P = (self.q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,self.r**2/(4*c*(t-self.tstart))))
                self.z = self.P/1e6 #= self.P/1e6
                result.append(self.z)
        return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Add yields instead of returns:

```
 def getPressure(self, t):    
    if (t-self.tstart<0):   
        yield None
        print "Startpunkt liegt außerhalb des Förderzeitraumes!"
    else:
        for x in range (xmin, xmax, xsteps):
            for y in range (ymin,ymax,ysteps):
                self.r = sqrt((x-self.xlage)**2+(y-self.ylage)**2)
                self.P = (self.q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,self.r**2/(4*c*(t-self.tstart))))
                self.z = self.P/1e6 #= self.P/1e6
                yield self.z
```

Then you use it like this :

```
for x in my_obj.getPressure(my_value):
    print x
```

or store it in a list like so:

```
my_list = list(my_obj.getPressure(my_value))
```